# Adding numbers from two files (line by line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have two files, both have about 10 lines of random numbers. I want to add each line in file1 with the corresponding line in file2. I can do it with only one number in each file but having multiple lines with numbers struggling with it. e.g
This is what I tried:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt").read()
file2 = open("file2.txt").read() 
result = int(file1) + int(file2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Try by reading line by line of both text documents. What you are doing is you are reading the whole file. You could do this in many of ways, like making an array reading each number in txt file 1 and another array to read txt file 2. Then you could add all values together and print them out. That's just one method of doing this, definitely not the most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to correctly get the numbers from the files (where your program fails) then add them, possibly in a new list. To make a more robust program, we will catch a trivial edge case (when the two list don't have the same number of arguments), as a bonus, you don't have to hardcode the number of lines in each file:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

try:
    with open("file1") as file1, open("file2") as file2:
        numbers1 = [int(line) for line in file1.readlines()]
        numbers2 = [int(line) for line in file2.readlines()]
        result = [line[0] + line[1] for line in zip_longest(numbers1, numbers2, fillvalue=0)]
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Error opening files")
```

Sample test:

file1:

```
7
1
5
9
7
9
10
3
10
8
```

file2:

```
9
9
8
2
8
5
2
8
9
```

```
>>> result
[16, 10, 13, 11, 15, 14, 12, 11, 19, 8]
```

You must notice that the files don't have the same number of lines, file1(10), file2(9), I took this example to show the level of incertitude in your condition:

> both have about 10 lines of random numbers

Comment: I was also told to make sure to close the file after reading it, more a good practice. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readlines` with `open` to get the lines as a Python list. Then, you can just add them one by one and make a new list with the sum.

As you said, **both have about 10 lines of random numbers** assuming both lists have same length.

```
numbers1 = [int(a) for a in open('file1.txt').readlines()]
numbers2 = [int(a) for a in open('file2.txt').readlines()]

resul_ls = []
for i in range(len(numbers1)):
   result_ls.append(numbers1[i] + numbers2[i])
```

Comment: 10 lines of random numbers = 10 random ints

Answer (score 2):

Just a note that if you have very long files it might be a bad idea to read them all into memory at once. In that case you can iterate over them at the same time using `zip`:

```
with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        print(int(line1) + int(line2))
```